# Jolt Transform on Nested JSON Object Array

Tags: json, nested, apache-nifi, jolt

Would like to flatten JUST the properties nested JSON, but still work for all objects in the input array

Having trouble putting all three together in one spec (type field, geo field, properties field). I wrote specs to do each one individually, but when I combine the specs to be of use together in one object, it produces the wrong output - the array of objects really messes it up.

Thanks!

Input:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiLineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            -11.11,
            11.11
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "tester_email": "tester123@123.com",
      "phase_test": "Test 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature22222",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiLineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            -11.11,
            11.11
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "tester_email": "tester123@123.com",
      "phase_test": "Test 1"
    }
  }
]
```

JOLT Spec:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": "[&1].type",
        "geometry": "[&1].geometry",
        "properties": "[&1]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Current Output:

```
[ [ {
  "type" : "Feature",
  "geometry" : {
    "type" : "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates" : [ [ [ -11.11, 11.11 ] ] ]
  }
}, {
  "tester_email" : "tester123@123.com",
  "phase_test" : "Test 1"
} ], [ {
  "type" : "Feature22222",
  "geometry" : {
    "type" : "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates" : [ [ [ -11.11, 11.11 ] ] ]
  }
}, {
  "tester_email" : "tester123@123.com",
  "phase_test" : "Test 1"
} ] ]
```

Desired Output:

```
[ {
"type" : "Feature",
"geometry" : {
  "type" : "MultiLineString",
  "coordinates" : [ [ [ -11.11, 11.11 ] ] ]
},
"tester_email" : "tester123@123.com",
"phase_test" : "Test 1"
},{
"type" : "Feature22222",
"geometry" : {
  "type" : "MultiLineString",
  "coordinates" : [ [ [ -11.11, 11.11 ] ] ]
},
"tester_email" : "tester123@123.com",
"phase_test" : "Test 1"
} ]
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "properties": {
          "type": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "properties": {
          "*": "[&2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```